# Convert Gradle from Groovy to Kotlin DSL (for liquibase-gradle-plugin)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy, liquibase

Here's my Gradle file using liquibase-gradle-plugin in Groovy DSL:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'liquibase'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
}

task('dev') {
    doLast {
        println "executing dev"
        liquibase {
            activities {
                main {
                    changeLogFile 'C:\\Users\\redacted\\IdeaProjects\\Food\\src\\main\\resources\\changelog.xml'
                    url 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb'
                    username 'postgres'
                    password 'redacted'
                }
            }
        }
        println "Done running dev."
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt at converting the file over to Kotlin DSL instead:

```
plugins {
    id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1")
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5")
    add("liquibaseRuntime", "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1")
    add("liquibaseRuntime", "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.1")
    add("liquibaseRuntime", "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5")
}

tasks.register("dev") {
    doLast {
        println("executing dev")
        "liquibase" {
            "activities" {
                "main" {
                    "changeLogFile"("C:\\Users\\redacted\\IdeaProjects\\Food\\src\\main\\resources\\changelog.xml")
                    "url"("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb")
                    "username"("postgres")
                    "password"("redacted")
                }
            }
        }
        println("Done running dev")
    }
}
```

It all falls apart at the line `"liquibase"`. I'm not familiar enough with Gradle - in the groovy version of the file, how is `liquibase` being resolved? What is it resolving to - is it a function? How do I get it to be resolved the same in the Kotlin version? Then under that, I'll also need to resolve `activities`, `main`, `changeLogFile`, `url`, `username`, and `password`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try to move the configuration of the liquibase extension to the top level:

```
plugins {
  id("org.liquibase.gradle") version "2.0.1"
}

...

liquibase {
    activities.register("main") {
        this.arguments = mapOf(
                "logLevel" to "info",
                "changeLogFile" to "src/main/resources/db.changelog.xml",
                "url" to "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbName",
                "username" to "userName",
                "password" to "secret")
    }
}

tasks.register("dev") {
   // depend on the liquibase status task
   dependsOn("update")
}
```

Comment: I probably spent 8 hours across three days trying to figure this out myself. I need to remember to post questions on stackoverflow quicker rather than spend so long and get nowhere... this works.